# Help with Maclaurin Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am working on finding a Maclaurin series for this function.

$$f(x) =x^6e^{x^7}$$

So I think I have to evaulate the above function based on a Maclaurin series for $e^x$ = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^n\over n!}$

I am just confused on how to connect the two series, and substitute the above function into the Maclaurin series for $e^x$

Can someone please help with explaining the first few steps? Thank Alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^u=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{u^n}{n!} ,$$
then if $u=x^7$, we have
$$e^{x^7}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x^7)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{7n}}{n!}. $$

Then,
$$f(x) =x^6 e^{x^7}=x^6\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{7n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{7n+6}}{n!}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you were just asked to write the Maclaurin series for $ \ e^{x^7} \ , $ you would insert $ \ x^7 \ $ in place of $ \ x \ $ in the series you have for $ \ e^x \ . $

Now, what is the derivative of $ \ e^{x^7} \ $ ?  How could you then use the series you have for $ \ e^{x^7} \  $ to write one for $ \ x^6 \ e^{x^7} \ $  ?